# Linux user specific virtual networks

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, libvirt, nat

We have a linux environment that is used by a number of users. Those users use some software that sends and receives udp socket data. We currently have a configuration file that allows specifying the bound port so that they can use the applications at the same time as each other.

We have a number of applications and a number of users which means the configuration file becomes unruly to manage.

I am hoping to instead setup some form of virtualised network whereby each user has a sandboxed environment that allows them to use the same udp ports as each other at the same time.

I've played around with libvirt and can get a virtualised subnet system wide, but I would like to stick that behind NAT or iptables rules or something similar that becomes user specific (and that they don't have to manage themselves). I would like to avoid running dockerised containers for each user if possible.

Is this something that should be possible?

Thanks! AJ

Comment: It sounds like per-user netns is what you desire. I do have a setup that attach the user manager (the per-user systemd service, you know) of a user to a netns and starts a WM (i3 / sway) with some `systemd-run --user` wrappers. It may not be deemed exactly mass-deployable though, and if you want to do it with DE and/or DM, it might be even trickier, if feasible at all. (Also I didn't attempt to cover anything like ssh in, but just the local graphical environment.)

Comment: If ssh in is exactly what you are talking about, similar approach might be adoptable if you keep a persistent tmux server process as a user service and enable lingering for the users. (I have no idea if there's a way to make login sessions spawned to always attach to a specific netns as per the user, like whether they are affected by the netns the user manager is in; maybe you can set netns for the user slice instead; haven't tried yet).

Comment: Thanks Tom. I discovered namespaces shortly after posting this, I played with them briefly but couldn't get anything tangible going. Its good to know that it should be possible, I'll keep trying.